# SQL: Full-Identifier in Resultset

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Perhaps this question has been answered already, but my search did not found any solution.

**Problem:**

In Oracle I have to join a lot of tables and return all columns. My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1,Table2,Table3,...
```

The result may look something like this:

```
Column1 | Column2 | ... | Column100 | ...
-----------------------------------------
  123   | Hello   | ... | World     | ...
  456   | Jon     | ... | Doe       | ...
...
```

If a later automated analysis shows an error in `Column100` I have no idea to which Table the column belongs.

**Question:**

Is it possible to use the `*` selector and get an result like:

```
Schema1.Table1.Column1 | Schema1.Table1.Column2 | ... | Schema3.Table5.Column100 | ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          123          |        Hello           | ... |        World             | ...
          456          |        Jon             | ... |        Doe               | ...
...
```

I am using the SQL-Developer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the below to get the details

```
  select 'SELECT '||
     listagg(owner||'.'||table_name||'.'||column_name,',') within group 
     (order by column_id)
    ||' FROM '||owner||'.'||'TEST_DATA'
     from dba_tab_Cols where table_name='TEST_DATA'
     group by owner;
```

This will generate the below which you can use to select the data

```
SELECT SCOT.TEST_DATA.ID,SCOT.TEST_DATA.VALUE FROM SCOT.TEST_DATA;
```

Comment: Very nice. Still work for each table, but time save and error proove, i.e., missing a column.

Comment: You can try for each table and find the issue for column100 based on column id

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that won't work. You have to name all those columns, one by one, using appropriate aliases. For example:

```
select d.deptno as dept_deptno,   --> this
       e.deptno as emp_deptno,    --> and this
       d.dname,
       e.ename
from emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
```

If you use `*`, you'll simply get `deptno, deptno_1` as column names for duplicates. If they aren't duplicates, true - you won't know which table they belong to.

Moreover, if you attempt to create a view (or a table, using CTAS), it won't work either as you'd get duplicate column names (i.e. Oracle won't add suffix as in `deptno_1`) so you **must** alias those columns.

Comment: Using aliases was my plan B. To save time I was hoping for a magical flag in Oracle...